# How to change VBA generated reports to SSRS

Tags: ms-access, reporting-services, vba, ssrs-2012

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask, so if not, please direct me accordingly.

I would like to know what the best process would be to change VBA generated excel reports into SSRS reports.

A bit of background, I work for a client who have been generating weekly, monthly and ad-hoc MS Excel reports via VBA macros. Currently, it was a manual process where they need to specify the report to run by calling a VBA macro function directly within MS Access. This macro would then run through all its underlying macro functions in order to generate the MS Excel report based on predefined configurations.

Since macros have become unsupported from Office 2007 (I think), the client is obligated to completely move away from this way of reporting to a fully automated process.

So, how would I go about interpreting the existing macros and generating the SSRS report accordingly?

Comment: Why do you think macros are unsupported in Office? Is your data stored in Access? Are you planning on moving that to SQL Server also?

Comment: Probably should've done my homework regarding the unsupported macros claim... The data currently sits in Access yes, but will be moved to SQL Server. So once that has been done, the reporting phase will kick off

Comment: You can link the SQL Server tables into Access, and continue to use the existing VBA to create the reports. If you want (or must) create SSRS reports, I doubt you can re-use any existing code, only the logic behind it to recreate the reports.

Comment: Ok, so it is going to be the hard way it seems.

Answer (score 0):

If the reports are from **Microsoft Access**, you can try importing the **Access** reports into **SSRS** with the **Import Reports** from the **Solution Explorer** window.

[image]

You'll probably need to make changes and set the datasources to your new location. I haven't actually done this so I can't say how successful it is.

You can then use the **Report Server**'s subscriptions to run the reports.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156375(v=sql.105).aspx